# Obfuscation and Compression of Deno Bundles

Tags: javascript, compression, bundle, obfuscation, deno

In WebPack, when I produce a bundle it obfuscates and compresses that bundle.

In [deno](https://deno.land/), the [bundler](https://deno.land/manual/tools/bundler) produces formatted code that is way more readable. I don't see any options for obfuscation or compression.

In deno, how would I accomplish an obfuscated and compressed bundle? I need something like WebPack that doesn't involve Visual Studio Code. What are some options? Do I just use node tools for this?

Comment: I see that [formatting](https://deno.land/manual/tools/formatter) can be turned off, but that's a far cry from [uglify](http://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/) when it comes to obfuscation, compression, and minification. Do I just need to figure out a workflow for using those same tools in deno?

Comment: As far as I understand you have to minify / uglify the output yourself as it's not part of 1.0.

Comment: @Jankapunkt Yeah, I guess in Deno, you can just write a javascript file to control the build. I just need to figure out which module to include in that script for minification, etc.

Comment: I see that https://deno.land/x/bundler@0.5.1 says "Bundler **does not yet** optimize or compress images with the --optimize option."

Answer (score 1):

One way I can suggest is to use a regex expression to systematically remove anything useful to a programmer or would be inspect element users.

I don't have the greatest example but this removes 99% of whitespace as well as all lines. A more aggressive approach would also rename most user-defined variables to a bunch of jargon like 'a', 'b', or 'aB'

```
const obfuscated = originalCode.replace(/\s+/g, " ").replace(/\n/g, "").replace(/\/\/# sourceMappingURL.*$/, "");
```

The last expression ran removes information about the bundle that would include the original files and imports which may otherwise pose a security risk if you're sending it to clients.

Though the question was asked 2 years ago I hope somebody finds this helpful.

Comment: That's a start, but [mangling](https://lisperator.net/uglifyjs/mangle) is a needed too.